# SQL Server license - Winforms or Web Application?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, winforms, windows-server-2008

We are currently using SQL Server 2008 Express Edition, but would like to upgrade to Standard Edition. Does it mean that we need a license with 20 seats, if we have 20 Active Directory users that are using the DB from a C# application?

If yes, does it make sense to switch from Windows Forms to Web Applications in order to decrease the amount of licenses needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Switching to a web app won't change the licensing needs of your application.  If you have 20 users connecting to your SQL Server then you need 20 CALs for Standard Edition as whilst you may have a single "user" connecting to the DB you're still servicing 20 users.  The MS license docs cover this in some detail.

The alternative approach for to go with per processor licenses.  You obviously need to do the maths to work out which option is more cost effective for your user growth estimates.

Given that you're starting at 20 users the per user (CAL) route will probably be the cheapest option.

Comment: Thanks Chris W. What, if we deploy a intranet web application where all users just sign in via login/password (member table) - without active directory. Can we use one CAL for that?

Comment: @Cosmo I don't believe that you can do that. You will still need to get a license for each user that uses the software even though there would only be one active directory user authenticating to the database. I have added a link in my answer where you can find a Quick Reference guide which provides a lot of information about licensing Sql Server.

Comment: No - you still have 20 users regardless of how you try to put something in the middle to minimise/pool connections.  The SQL license docs cover this and refer to it as multiplexing.  See here http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/7/3/8733d036-92b0-4cb8-8912-3b6ab966b8b2/multiplexing.doc

Comment: "SQL Server CALs are required for users who directly input into, query, or view data from a SQL Server database " - but isn't it the asp.net process, not the user? because that would mean that a website with 10 000 active visitors would need that many CALs.

Comment: With that many users you'd probably switch to a proc license instead as yes it gets expensive. You need a CAL per user who will be connecting. The asp.net process is the only physical connection but it's really just multiplexing. If you're doing a web application that's not intranet only then you're really forced to go the proc route. In your case you know & can control the users hence CALs are still a viable option.

Comment: So, just to be sure that I understand you. If I have a public website with 1000 visitors that are just reading my site, I need: a) 1000 CALs or b) a processor license? Is that correct?

Comment: If you know who the visitors are i.e. your controlling access then potentially you could license them on the CAL basis and yes you'd need 1000 CALs.  For most public apps you don't know who the users are hence you need to go down the per proc route to license the product (or alternatively host via a virtual/dedicated server at an ISP that offers SQL Server on a monthly rental basis instead - you'll note that you can run SQL Server on Amazon EC2 etc where the license charge is built in to the instance costs).

Answer (score 4):

You have two types of licenses available to you, each with their own set of rules and scenarios where they make sense.

1. Per Processor License. Here you license each physical (or virtual if you are using virtualization and depending on the Sql Server Edition) processors.
2. Server/CAL license. Here you would buy a license for each server running Sql Server and Client Access Licenses (CAL) for each user or device. Note that a CAL would allow that user or device to connect to any number of SQL Servers without the need to buy additional CALs if you add additional servers. Also, any type of software or hardware that reduces the number of devices or users that directly access SQL Server (an example would be the use of a web application to reduce the number of users that connect to the database directly through connection pooling) would NOT reduce the number of CALs you get. You will still need to get them for each user using the web application.

The following [microsoft link](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/pricing.aspx) provides pricing points for Sql Server 2008 and also includes a  Sql Server 2008 R2 Quick Reference, which includes all the information that you might need. We can see that based on the above link:

1. Per Processor would cost you $7,171.00
2. Server/CAL would end up being $4,178.00 based on the bellow calculations

Server $898.00
CAL $164.00 x 20 = $3,280
Total $898.00 + $3,280 = $4,178.00

Of course this is an estimate that doesn't include tax, discounts, or software assurance.

If you want more information I would recommend asking on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/)

Comment: Thanks Waleed Al-Balooshi, however I can just mark one answer as correct :/

Comment: @Cosmo Chris's answer deserves to be checked as the correct one, because 1. he answered it first 2. was providing you with the great additional explanations in his comments 3. I just wanted to add a few additional points to Chris's answer and link to that reference document, which I still recommend that you download. I am happy everything worked out for you :)